# Extreme lag with Sony Ericsson WT19i after update to 4.0.4

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, sony-live-with-walkman

I have updated my *Sony Ericsson Live with Walkman* to 4.0.4 from 2.3.4 and now the system lags horribly. I have to wait for a considerable time for an application to exit. Even the in built basic applications like phone and contacts take about 5-7 secs to load.

Has anyone faced a similar problem? What can I do that would cure my system of the lag?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Sony made the ICS upgrade a horrible experience which does slow down the handset and lag.

Two choices:

- downgrade to Gingerbread 2.3.x
- Try switching to custom ROM called [LegacyXperia](http://legacyxperia.github.io) to use JellyBean.

The experience is more satisfying and smooth. For that to happen:

- need `adb`, `fastboot` binaries
- if your bootloader can be unlocked, check [Sony](http://unlockbootloader.sonymobile.com/) **Warning** *if yes and proceed to do so, you will lose your data*
- you would need to backup your apps (there is other questions on this site about this topic!)
- download the LegacyXperia ROM, extract `boot.img` from zip, flash it to bootloader
- reboot and toggle volume keys to get into ClockworkMod Recovery
- choose wipe data/cache
- choose install from adb sideload, CWM will wait,
- `adb sideload name_of_zip_file`, CWM will start loading and installing the ROM.
- reboot and enjoy JellyBean.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated my phone as well, yesterday, and It's indeed quite slow at times. Here are two easy things you can do;

- Replace your home screen with LauncherPro, it's a lot faster
- If you're rooted, lower your *vmheapsize* (24m seems like a good value)

Now these small tweaks are probably going to be insufficient, but at least they're safe. The other thing you can do is to find the original Android 2.3 ROM for your device, and flash it to your device.